# php mysqli repeated fields in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I need to convert an existing project from mysql to mysqli and using prepared statement.

In the existing project there are queries that uses repeated variable values.
One such example is this: where the $prev_yr is used 3 times.

```
$sqlins = "Insert into studentclass (`StudentID`, `ClassID`, `Year`, `Level`, `SNo`, `TermList`, `DateStart`, `DateEnd`) 
            select StudentID, '$prev_cl', '$prev_yr', '$prev_lvl', '', '123456789', '$prev_yr-01-01', '$prev_yr-12-31' from student Where StudentID in ($ids) ";
```

Is there a better method than this:

```
$sqlins = "Insert into studentclass (`StudentID`, `ClassID`, `Year`, `Level`, `SNo`, `TermList`, `DateStart`, `DateEnd`) 
            select StudentID, '?', '?', '?', '', '123456789', '?-01-01', '?-12-31' from student Where StudentID in (?) ";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sqlins);
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $prev_cl,$prev_yr,$prev_lvl,$prev_yr,$prev_yr,$ids);
$stmt->execute();
```

I am wondering if there is a way of binding the $prev_yr once for all 3 occurrences.

Because there are other queries that may have 2 occurrences of $prev_lvl, 5 occurrences of $prev_yr etc in one statement. The idea is that when the repeated occurrences of multiple variables becomes many in a statement - it becomes quite confusing to arrange them in the bind_param.

Any solution?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can bind columns, as that is part of the `SELECT {field}` and not on the Where clause.

Comment: Thank you - learnt something here about binding only on Where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it even work like that, typical you wont't do this `'?-01-01'` in a query.  I haven't used Mysqli, in about 4 years, as all I use now a days is PDO.  But as far as I know when you send that to prepare it's gonna puke on the `?` being in a string.

I would split it, there actually is no real need to do the select because the only thing being selected is the studentID which you already have.  Simply

```
$insert = $mysqli->prepare("Insert into studentclass (`StudentID`, `ClassID`, `Year`, `Level`, `SNo`, `TermList`, `DateStart`, `DateEnd`)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

foreach( $ids AS $id ){
    $stmt->bind_param("issssiss", $id, $prev_cl,$prev_yr,$prev_lvl,'', '123456789', $prev_yr.'-01-01',$prev_yr.'-12-31');
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

I can't test it so hopefully I got everything in the right place.

As I said I don't think you can bind to the  `Fields` part of the query and certainly not inside a partial string, besides it's making a select that is un-needed.  Just make sure to prepare the insert before the loop.

Just to clearly the only thing that select actually gets from the DB is this

```
 select StudentID ... from student Where StudentID in (?)
```

The rest are added in as "fake" columns, I don't know the term for it.  It's difficult to read the original query..

Comment: I removed the dangerous part for your otherwise excellent answer.

Comment: Fair enough. dangerous for inexperienced developers, personly i avoid it just as a matter of best practice even if I know the data is clean.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Insightful to me, an inexperienced mysqli user. Hmm... looks like I may need to go into PDO way bec they have variables like :classx to do binding.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if there is a way of binding the $prev_yr once for all 3 occurrences.

No.

Besides, it wouldn't work this way anyway, as you cannot bind just an arbitrary query part of your choice. You can bind a complete data literal only. Means instead of '?-01-01' it should be just ?, whereas in your PHP code you should make it

```
$dateStart = "$prev_yr-01-01";
```

and then bind this variable for the whole value. So there will be no more repeating variables.

Comment: Thank you. That's insightful. Maybe another option can be concat(?,'-01-01') or concat(:year,'-01-01') if I am going into PDO?

Comment: surely you can use concat() in SQL instead, but to me it's too lenghty. I was going to add a remark about PDO, encouraging you to use it. It won't help with this issue but will make your code much more sensible.